# exhaustive list of jquery mobile data-roles?

Tags: jquery-mobile

In jquery mobile, you deal with data-roles a lot.  Is there a list of all data-roles in jquery-mobile?  I think I would find that helpful.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is the best list I can find.

source: http://api.jquerymobile.com/data-attribute/

```
data-add-back-btn 
data-ajax 
data-back 
data-back-btn-text 
data-collapsed 
data-count-theme 
data-direction 
data-divider-theme 
data-dividertheme 
data-filter 
data-filter-theme 
data-fullscreen 
data-grid 
data-icon 
data-iconpos 
data-id 
data-inline 
data-inset 
data-mynamespace-foo 
data-native 
data-native-menu 
data-placeholder 
data-position 
data-rel 
data-role 
data-split-icon 
data-split-theme 
data-theme 
data-track-theme 
data-transition 
data-type 
data-url
```

Comment: Thank you!  The documentation is hard to navigate.

Comment: I noticed that the link provided does have a data-role entry ... but the data-role entry does Not describe _data-role="popup"_ ... there could be other values that are not included.

Answer (score 37):

After the 1.0 release there is now an [official reference page for data attributes](http://api.jquerymobile.com/data-attribute/) (including roles).

Comment: To improve the quality of this question, this should be marked as the correct anser. Mine is potentially out-dated and incorrect.

Comment: The link in your answer is out of date now, it should be updated to http://api.jquerymobile.com/data-attribute/

Answer (score 9):

As Joe says, the documentation is hard to navigate we most developers are used to do.
There is not all possible values for data-role attribute documented.
You have to figure it out by reading the whole page.

So in my willing to help, this is what I got from documentation page:

**data-role** possible values:

- button
- collapsible
- collapsible-set
- content
- field-contain
- slider
- footer
- header
- listview
- navbar
- page

hope this helps, hope jquery update its doc page.

Comment: add these in here :
dialog
popup

Answer (score 1):

You can add your own data-role values for styling and extension purposes.